# Physical location of target in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating an app in IOS with `xcode 5.4.2`. Can anybody tell me the physical location of target in xcode. Which files store the build settings given in the target in xcode IDE?

Comment: Where did you find `Xcode 5.4.2`?

Comment: It is actually xcode 4.6, not 4.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the settings are stored in the "project.pbxproj" file inside the .xcodeproj file/folder, but this file isn't particularly easy to read.

- Right Click the .xcodeproj
- Click Show Package Contents
- project.pbxproj file is in there.